How To USE EVENT GRID NAMESPACE MQTT HOSTNAME ON ESP32 OR ESP32 ONLINE LIKE WOKWI to send Data like Temperature Or Humidity Using DHT22 SENSOR
im on a experiment with ESP32 or ESP32 online like WOKWI using DHT22 Sensors to send data like Temperature and Humidity to MQTT Receiver like MQTTx maybe.
right now i am on a experiment using event grid espescially event grid namespace using MQTT Broker support there. After i enabled the broker and set to Public Connection, can i use the MQTT Hostname to my ESP32 or ESP32 ONLINE like at WOKWI ?
i just want a simple esp32 with dht22 sensor sending data like temperature and humidity to MQTT client like MQTTx maybe
to do this, do i need to use another resource in Azure ? Or just using azure event grid namespace ?
i've trid same documentation like this :
`#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

// Wi-Fi settings
const char* ssid = "Wokwi-GUEST";
const char* password = "";

// Azure Event Grid settings
const char* mqttBroker = "eventgrid1.southeastasia-1.ts.eventgrid.azure.net";
const int mqttPort = 8883;
const char* eventGridTopic = "Topics/topic1";
const char* username = "client1-authnID";
const char* deviceID = "client1-sessionID1";

// TLS/SSL client setup
WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);

// Certificates
const char* caCert = "";

const char* clientCert = R"KEY(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)KEY";

const char* clientKey = R"KEY(
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIAb/hcl7cXX8gHH8gjlhXjcaj8pTonHP+MzqcS2rHY13oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEmvEdmUuMBNnORlOjAKVjP7vRe/0KNQ0YUulT7K9s2tDk17jvQoTh
N7acbvBt/67MjOGz4/SOgwGTHmx1221/0w==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
)KEY";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Load CA certificate, client certificate, and client key
  wifiClient.setCACert(caCert);
  wifiClient.setCertificate(clientCert);
  wifiClient.setPrivateKey(clientKey);

  // Set MQTT server and port
  mqttClient.setServer(mqttBroker, mqttPort);

  // Set MQTT callback function
  mqttClient.setCallback(callback);

  // Connect to MQTT broker
  connectToMqttBroker();
}

void loop() {
  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    // Reconnect to MQTT broker if the connection is lost
    connectToMqttBroker();
  }
  mqttClient.loop();

  // Publish message to Event Grid
  publishEvent();

  // Delay before publishing the next event
  delay(5000);
}

void connectToMqttBroker() {
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT broker...");

    if (mqttClient.connect(username, deviceID,"")) {
      Serial.println("Connected to MQTT broker");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" Retrying in 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  // Handle incoming MQTT messages here if needed
}

void publishEvent() {
  // Create the event message
  DynamicJsonDocument eventMessage(256);
  eventMessage["id"] = "1";
  eventMessage["subject"] = "Example Event";
  eventMessage["eventType"] = "example.event";
  JsonObject eventData = eventMessage.createNestedObject("data");
  eventData["key"] = "value";

  // Serialize the event message to a JSON string
  String jsonMessage;
  serializeJson(eventMessage, jsonMessage);

  // Publish the event message to Event Grid
  mqttClient.publish(eventGridTopic, jsonMessage.c_str());
}`

but always get problem like this :
Failed, rc=-2 Retrying in 5 seconds...

Connecting to MQTT broker...

you can use the Azure Event Grid MQTT Broker for handling your solution, where an ESP32 will publish a sensor telemetry data on the topic and the MQTTx Client can subscribed on this topic. This scenario has been successfully tested with M5Stack products such as AtomS3Lite (ESP32-S3) and AtomLite (ESP32-PICO) using a nanoFramework (C#).

Can I have the documentation sir or the source that I can use to solve my problem??

have a look at the MQTT Client Library for .Net nanoFramework: https://github.com/nanoframework/nanoFramework.m2mqtt/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file

In prior of coding for ESP32, I do recommend using the MQTTx Client tool for both sides such as a publisher and subscriber to validate your connectivity to the Azure Event Grid MQTT Broker, etc.

If u look my code, can u tell me where is the main problem sir ?

Did you try to use the MQTTx Client to connect and publish some data on the topic based on the parameters (certificate, username, etc.) used in your code?

Yes, but no code. I use MQTTx with enabled TLS And input the Certificate and it's going well to publish and subscribe data. But with code, it's Eror just like the code above

My condition I have to use with code on esp32 to connect to Azure Event grid Namepspace in my MQTT hostname in there

The following is a working sample of the ESP32-S3 MQTT Client to publish a pressed button on the topic of the Azure Event Grid MQTT Broker. The publisher is written using the .NET nanoFramework.
using Iot.Device.Button;
using nanoFramework.M2Mqtt;
using nanoFramework.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using nanoFramework.Networking;
using nanoFramework.Runtime.Native;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace NFAppM5StampS3_MQTT_Broker
{
    public class Program
    {
        static string ssid = "xxxxxx";
        static string password = "xxxxxx";
        //
        static string deviceId = "device2";
        static string username = "device2";
        static string brokerHostName = "xxxxxx.westeurope-1.ts.eventgrid.azure.net";
        static string pub_topic = "abc/test/button";
        //
        static MqttClient device = null;
        static int pinButton = 0;
        

        public static void Main()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello from nanoFramework!");
            GpioButton buttonM5 = new GpioButton(buttonPin: pinButton);

            try
            {
                #region Connect to WiFi
                CancellationTokenSource cs = new(60000);
                if (WifiNetworkHelper.ScanAndConnectDhcp(ssid, password, requiresDateTime: true, token: cs.Token))
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Wifi ready - {ssid}");
                else
                    throw new Exception($"Wifi is not connected.");
                #endregion

                #region MQTT Connection
                var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(client_cert, client_key, "");
                device = new MqttClient(brokerHostName, 8883, true, null, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
                device.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_5;
                device.Settings.ValidateServerCertificate = false;  //no CA signed server! 
                var ret = device.Connect(deviceId, username, "");
                if (ret != MqttReasonCode.Success)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"MQTT ERROR connecting: {ret}");
                    device.Disconnect();
                    throw new Exception("Device failed to connect it");
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(">>> Device is connected");
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Power.RebootDevice();
            }

            #region ButtonPress          
            buttonM5.Press += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The Button has been pressed");
                string payload = $"{{\"counter\":{counter++}}}";
                device.Publish(pub_topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), "application/json; charset=utf-8", null);
            };
            #endregion

            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);            
        }

        #region Certificates
        private const string client_cert = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

        private const string client_key = @"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
        #endregion
    }
}

The following screen snippet shows a subscriber MQTTx Client tool with receiving on the topic, where the button published a message:

and the following screen snippet shows the Event Grid messages received on this topic forwarded to the AEG Subscribers.

Note, that the telemetry data from the sensors is a straightforward work. It can be published to the AEG MQTT Broker based on the timer each minute.
Update:
The following is the packages.config file used in the above code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="nanoFramework.CoreLibrary" version="1.15.5" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.Iot.Device.Button" version="1.2.536" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.M2Mqtt" version="5.1.123" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.Runtime.Events" version="1.11.15" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.Runtime.Native" version="1.6.12" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Collections" version="1.5.31" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Device.Gpio" version="1.1.38" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Device.Wifi" version="1.5.81" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.IO.Streams" version="1.1.59" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Net" version="1.10.77" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Text" version="1.2.54" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
  <package id="nanoFramework.System.Threading" version="1.1.32" targetFramework="netnano1.0" />
</packages>


Ok sir I will try to use your help

can i use this on wokwi sir ?

The above sample is using  https://www.nanoframework.net/ where C# developers can use their IDE (Microsoft Visual Studio, ...) for embedded applications on microcontrollers such as ESP32, etc. You have to check, if the Wokwi simulator can support the .Net nanoFramework.

Esp32 and ESP32-S3 just the same right ? But ESP32-S3 is more features than esp32 regular. I have the esp32 instead. Can I use that in esp32 regular?

Yes, you can use it.

may i see ur documentation of your code above ? maybe your github or the file that i can see. I want to see the nuget package manager and the detail of your configuration

see the file packages.config added into my answer.
